# error to add EditText value to ListView using BaseAdapter by clicking Button

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

i am new to android,help with the code how add EditText value to ListView using BaseAdapter by clicking Button.
when i enter value in EditText and by clicking Add Button, value must place in ListViw(ListView must have BaseAdapter only).
here tried with code found with error,help me to complete my code

ListDataActivity.java

```
public class ListDataActivity {
    String myData;

    public String getMyData() {
        return myData;
    }

    public void setMyData(String myDataa) {
        myData = myDataa;
    }
}
```

BaseAdapterActivity.java

```
public class MyBaseAdapterActivity extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<ListDataActivity> list = new ArrayList<ListDataActivity>();
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;

    public MyBaseAdapterActivity(Context context, ArrayList<ListDataActivity> list) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        MyViewHolder myViewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_addlist, parent, false);
            myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(myViewHolder);
        } else {
            myViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        ListDataActivity listDataActivity = getItemId(position);

        myViewHolder.mydata.setText(listDataActivity.getMyData());

        return convertView;
    }

    private class MyViewHolder {
        String mydata;

        public MyViewHolder(View item) {
            mydata = (ListView) item.findViewById(R.id.myData);
        }
    }
}
```

AddListActivity.java

```
public class AddlistActivity extends Activity {
    ListView lstName;
    Button btnAdd;
    EditText edtName;
    String myData;
    Context context = AddlistActivity.this;
    ArrayList<ListDataActivity> list = new ArrayList<ListDataActivity>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_addlist);

        lstName = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst_name);
        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
        edtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_name);
        getDataInList();

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myData = edtName.getText().toString().trim();
            }
        });

        lstName.setAdapter(new MyBaseAdapterActivity(context, list));
    }

    private void getDataInList() {
        for (int i = 0; i < myData.length(); i++) {
            ListDataActivity listDataActivity = new ListDataActivity();
            listDataActivity.setMyData(myData[i]);
            list.add(listDataActivity);
        }
    }
}
```

my error

> Error:(48, 46) error: array required, but String found
>   C:\Users\Rahul\Documents\AndroidStudioWorkSpace\LoginDataBaseTask\app\src\main\java\com\example\rahul\logindatabasetask\MyBaseAdapterActivity.java
>   Error:(57, 54) error: incompatible types: long cannot be converted to ListDataActivity
>   Error:(59, 28) error: cannot find symbol method setText(String)
>   Error:(68, 52) error: cannot find symbol variable myData
>   Error:(68, 20) error: incompatible types: ListView cannot be converted to String
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: In your case myData is string variable, then are you iterating loop for string length. Jus add that string to list, then call notifyDataSetChanged() on adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you're doing wrong here.

```
 myViewHolder.mydata.setText(listDataActivity.getMyData());
```

**mydata** is just a `String`. It's not an Object of `EditText`. So better to add **EditText** in your `ViewHolder`. and initialized it before used.

Answer (score 0):

In your AddListActivity.java, myData is String. So you cannot use

```
listDataActivity.setMyData(myData[i]);
```

Its represent to the array. simply call your getDataInList() method inside onclick
method

```
 btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        myData=edtName.getText().toString().trim();
        getDataInList();
        ((BaseAdapter)lstName.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

and inside getDataInList(),  remove for loop and use just myData, not myData[i].

Comment: Error in my BaseAdapterActivity"Error:(57, 54) error: incompatible types: long cannot be converted to ListDataActivity
Error:(59, 28) error: cannot find symbol method setText(String)
Error:(68, 52) error: cannot find symbol variable myData
Error:(68, 20) error: incompatible types: ListView cannot be converted to String
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details." @swapnilMeshram

Comment: whats inside your activity_addlist.xml?

Comment: if you want to show string, you should not use listview inside activity_addlist.xml. You have to use TextView to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Make your adapter as global,and Set adapter to listview.

something like this:

```
 adapter = new MyBaseAdapterActivity(context, list);
 lstName.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Set editText data to ListDataACtivity.

```
btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      String myData=edtName.getText().toString().trim();
      getDataInList(myData);
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
});
```

Change your getDataInList() to:

```
   private void getDataInList(String myData) {
        ListDataActivity listDataActivity = new ListDataActivity();
        listDataActivity.setMyData(myData);
        list.add(listDataActivity);
}
```